# How to extract keywords (strings) from a list in a column in a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of strings that have spaces in them:

```
lst = ["apple pie", "chocolate shakes", "orange juice"]
```

and I have a series:

```
       Explanation 

a      "apple pie is my favorite dessert" 
b      "I love chocolate. But I love chocolate shakes more." 
c      "she is allergic to orange juice"
```

and I'm looking to get something like this:

```
        Explanation                                         Explanation Extracted

a      "apple pie is my favorite dessert"                           "apple pie"
b      "I love chocolate. But I love chocolate shakes more."      "chocolate shakes"
c      "she is allergic to orange juice"                          "orange juice"
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example, there is a handy built-in [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function that seems like exactly what you need

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend you use `str.findall`, since you may have mutiple match within one sentence

```
df['Explanation Extracted'] = df['Explanation'].str.findall('|'.join(lst))
df
Out[193]: 
                                         Explanation Explanation Extracted
0                  apple pie is my favorite dessert            [apple pie]
1  I love chocolate. But I love chocolate shakes ...    [chocolate shakes]
2                   she is allergic to orange juice         [orange juice]
```